# Nginx is blocking Http DELETE requests

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, nginx-config

I am currently running a project that utilizes both Angular and Spring frameworks, and it's deployed on a local Ubuntu server. For an unknown reason, my Nginx setup is blocking all HTTP DELETE requests and returning a **405 Method Not Allowed error message**. To troubleshoot this issue, I've conducted tests by running the backend directly and sending DELETE requests via Postman. The requests work as expected in that environment, indicating that the problem likely lies within the Nginx configuration.

Below is my current Nginx configuration for your reference:
**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/app.example.com**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name app.example.com;

        location / {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name  app.example.com;

        ssl_certificate /home/ssl.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/private-key.pem;

        root /home/angular/dist;

        location / {
                #alias /home/angular/dist;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location ~ ^/api/ {
                rewrite ^/api(.*) /api/auth/$1 break;
                proxy_pass https://localhost:8080;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_ssl_verify off;
        }
}
```

Any assistance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.